# Svelte, Tailwind and CustomElements API

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, vite, web-component, custom-element

I want to build a customElement with Svelte and TailwindCSS. I use the global flag in style, but the element is not styled. Before enabling the customElement API it was workign as intended.

When runnning with vite I get a lot of svelte(unused-css-selector) warnings - which looks to me that the css stuff is removed on compile time. How can I avoid this? I thought the global option would do this.

**MyElement.svelte**

```
<svelte:options customElement="myElement" />

<script lang="ts">
  let config = {};
</script>

<div>Hello World from CustomElement</div>
<slot />

<style global lang="postcss">
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
</style>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Svelte CustomElement Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
    <my-element />
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import MyElement from './MyElement.svelte';

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement.element);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding your styles via <svelte:head> in your Custom Element?